# Unreal Engine Niagara Particle Velocity Based on Density of Particles?

Tags: unreal-4, particles, unreal

Goal: Simulation of particles where each particle moves to the direction with the highest density out of candidate directions.

I'm not sure how to do the following operations using UE Niagara.

- How to look at the positions of other particles within a Niagara Emitter. I know how to access to the position of other emitters using event handlers.
- How to read the positions of particles that are in a certain region in the 3D space (eg. within the bounding box of (0,0,0) (1,1,1)) efficiently.

Please feel free to suggest any other features within UE, but I think Niagara is the way to go.

Comment: What exactly is the desired result visual-wise? Assuming all particles spawn randomly, isn't this the same as picking a random spot and having all particles move towards it?

Comment: For example, it looks at its back and front and decides the direction. So not necessarily they all gather to a point.

Comment: Do you mean the particles will only move either forwards or backwards? This is very important information that you should probably include in your question. Initially I thought they are meant to have 3D movement. Maybe you can show a picture or two of what you want to do.

Comment: https://twitter.com/kleptine/status/1194289888339693568?s=21 This example is 2D but I'm hoping to do this in 3D. So the basic idea is that each particle defines 3 random directions and move to the direction with the maximum density. For this, I need to access the positional information of other particles.

Comment: This is a very nice gif that describes nicely what you are looking for. I'd suggest to edit your question and add it, so other viewers can see what you are trying to create.